# Hadoop : Error during the operation -copyFromLocal

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

Hi I am getting the following error when tried to execute -copyFromLocal command on Hadoop.
Could anyone pls help by suggesting a solution to fix this issue?

```
 hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/AReport.txt /user/
13/09/24 19:42:38 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/AReport.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:596)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:523)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1383)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1379)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1377)
```

Here is the report details.

```
 $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report
    Configured Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
    Present Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
    DFS Remaining: 0 (0 KB)
    DFS Used: 0 (0 KB)
    DFS Used%: ?%
    Under replicated blocks: 0
    Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
    Missing blocks: 0

    -------------------------------------------------
    Datanodes available: 0 (0 total, 0 dead)
```

Comment: You don't have ANY datanodes. On my pseudo installed Hadoop my last line looks like `Datanodes available: 1 (1 total, 0 dead)`. Try `jps` as root. Does it list `datanodes`? Maybe the service is not running
`

Comment: Yep, the datnodes were not working... Now after removing tmp files one of the node is up and running... Now its showing as Datanodes available: 1 (1 total, 0 dead). But I would like to know which among the two data nodes are not working... So that I can go to that particular node and fix the problem...

Comment: But it seems you only have a single datanode. How many machines do you have in your cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could find the out the solution for the problem..

All the data nodes were down. Deleting the tmp files on the nodes gave the solution..

Answer (score 1):

use  `hadoop datanode -start` OR `hadoop datanode -rollback`

Comment: I tried wiht that but it didn't help. Would like to know whethe the below details are as expected..?****************/
[hduser@hadoop-vm03 bin]$ jps
25382 Jps
24427 NameNode
24768 JobTracker
24889 TaskTracker
24669 SecondaryNameNode
[hduser@hadoop-vm03 bin]$ hadoop dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used: 0 (0 KB)
DFS Used%: ?%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 0 (0 total, 0 dead)

Comment: your datanode process is not running so what `hadoop datanode -rollback ` return